# Get GraphQL whole schema query

Tags: schema, graphql

I want to get the schema from the server.
I can get all entities with the types but I'm unable to get the properties.

Getting all types:

```
query {
  __schema {
    queryType {
      fields {
        name
        type {
          kind
          ofType {
            kind
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to get the properties for type:

```
__type(name: "Person") {
    kind
    name
    fields {
      name
      type {
        kind
        name
        description
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I get all types with the properties in only 1 request? Or ever better: How can I get the whole schema with the mutators, enums, types ...

Comment: I ended using the introspectionQuery from 'graphql'; as described at the bottom. It's fine.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

**Update**

Using [`graphql-cli`](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-cli) is now the recommended workflow to get and update your schema.

The following commands will get you started:

```
# install via NPM
npm install -g graphql-cli

# Setup your .graphqlconfig file (configure endpoints + schema path)
graphql init

# Download the schema from the server
graphql get-schema
```

You can even listen for schema changes and continuously update your schema by running:

```
graphql get-schema --watch
```

---

> In case you just want to download the GraphQL schema, use the following approach:

The easiest way to get a GraphQL schema is using the CLI tool [get-graphql-schema](https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema).

You can install it via NPM:

```
npm install -g get-graphql-schema
```

There are two ways to get your schema. 1) [GraphQL IDL](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphql-idl-schema-definition-language-kr84dktnp0/) format or 2) JSON introspection query format.

### GraphQL IDL format

```
get-graphql-schema ENDPOINT_URL > schema.graphql
```

### JSON introspection format

```
get-graphql-schema ENDPOINT_URL --json > schema.json
```

or

```
get-graphql-schema ENDPOINT_URL -j > schema.json
```

For more information you can refer to the following tutorial: [How to download the GraphQL IDL Schema](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphql-how-to-download-graphql-idl-schema-maiv5eekan/)

Comment: The answer that was marked the solution was not implementable with the GraphQL server I was trying to use but this library did exactly what was required to generate a full schema. It probably should be marked the solution.

Comment: The --json should go before the >

Comment: @Catharz: Nowhere does the question state that the OP does not want to use Node or JavaScript. Furthermore, this answer does not require using JavaScript _libraries_; it presents a command-line tool that happens to be _written_ in JavaScript.

Comment: I followed the step and `graphql get-schema` doesn't write to the schema.graphql file. It output to the screen, however. I don't know why.

Comment: how to pass authentication header to the  `graphql get-schema`

Comment: This answer is actually out of date - see https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-cli/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION.md#get-schema-is-no-longer-available

Re headers, you in your gql config you can do `schema: { YOUR/ENDPOINT: { headers: {Authorization: "Token your_token"}}}`

Comment: `graphql get-schema` does not do anything for me - prints nothing, does not throw an error. `get-graphql-schema` says Authorization is not a correct header. `Insomnia` uses this header just fine.

Comment: It seems `get-schema` was removed from graphql-cli, or at the very least moved to an optional module

Comment: I coouldn't get `graphql-cli` to work (and it seems to be a somewhat abandoned project). This works though: https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/schema-ast

Answer (score 101):

This is the query that [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql) uses (network capture):

```html
query IntrospectionQuery {
  __schema {
    queryType {
      name
    }
    mutationType {
      name
    }
    subscriptionType {
      name
    }
    types {
      ...FullType
    }
    directives {
      name
      description
      locations
      args {
        ...InputValue
      }
    }
  }
}

fragment FullType on __Type {
  kind
  name
  description
  fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
    name
    description
    args {
      ...InputValue
    }
    type {
      ...TypeRef
    }
    isDeprecated
    deprecationReason
  }
  inputFields {
    ...InputValue
  }
  interfaces {
    ...TypeRef
  }
  enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
    name
    description
    isDeprecated
    deprecationReason
  }
  possibleTypes {
    ...TypeRef
  }
}

fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
  name
  description
  type {
    ...TypeRef
  }
  defaultValue
}

fragment TypeRef on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The same query is used by [Postwoman](https://postwoman.io/graphql/), but the UI only shows the relevant types when you click on the "Get schema" button.

Answer (score 19):

You can use GraphQL-JS's introspection query to get everything you'd like to know about the schema:

```
import { introspectionQuery } from 'graphql';
```

If you want just the information for types, you can use this:

```
{
    __schema: {
        types: {
            ...fullType
        }
    }
}
```

Which uses the following fragment from the introspection query:

```
fragment FullType on __Type {
    kind
    name
    description
    fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
      name
      description
      args {
        ...InputValue
      }
      type {
        ...TypeRef
      }
      isDeprecated
      deprecationReason
    }
    inputFields {
      ...InputValue
    }
    interfaces {
      ...TypeRef
    }
    enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
      name
      description
      isDeprecated
      deprecationReason
    }
    possibleTypes {
      ...TypeRef
    }
  }
  fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
    name
    description
    type { ...TypeRef }
    defaultValue
  }
  fragment TypeRef on __Type {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
                ofType {
                  kind
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

If that seems complicated, it's because fields can be arbitrarility deeply wrapped in nonNulls and Lists, which means that technically even the query above does not reflect the full schema if your fields are wrapped in more than 7 layers (which probably isn't the case).

You can see the source code for introspectionQuery [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/utilities/introspectionQuery.js).

Comment: This should be at the top!

Comment: In newer versions of `graphql` this is now a function called `getIntrospectionQuery()`

Answer (score 19):

Using [apollo cli](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/code-generation/codegen-cli#fetch-schema):

```
npx apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/graphql schema.json
```

Comment: use 

npx apollo client:download-schema --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/graphql schema.json

Comment: link returns 404

Comment: @Raj just fixed

Answer (score 12):

#### Update

After getting sick of modifying my previous script all the time, I caved and made my own CLI tool [gql-sdl](https://github.com/jkmartindale/gql-sdl). I still can't find a different tool that can download GraphQL SDL with zero config but would love for one to exist.

Basic usage:

```bash
$ gql-sdl https://api.github.com/graphql -H "Authorization: Bearer ghp_[redacted]"
directive @requiredCapabilities(requiredCapabilities: [String!]) on OBJECT | SCALAR | ARGUMENT_DEFINITION | INTERFACE | INPUT_OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION | ENUM | ENUM_VALUE | UNION | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION

"""Autogenerated input type of AbortQueuedMigrations"""
input AbortQueuedMigrationsInput {
  """The ID of the organization that is running the migrations."""
  ownerId: ID!

  """A unique identifier for the client performing the mutation."""
  clientMutationId: String
}
...
```

The header argument `-H` is technically optional but most GraphQL APIs require authentication via headers. You can also download the JSON response instead (`--json`) but that's a use case already well served by other tools.

Under the hood this still uses the introspection query provided by [GraphQL.js](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js), so if you're looking to incorporate this functionality into your own code see the example below.

---

#### Previous answer

Somehow I wasn't able to get any of the suggested CLI tools to output the schema in GraphQL's Schema Definition Language (SDL) instead of the introspection result JSON. I ended up throwing together a really quick Node script to make the GraphQL library do it for me:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const { buildClientSchema, getIntrospectionQuery, printSchema } = require("graphql");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

async function saveSchema(endpoint, filename) {
    const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query: getIntrospectionQuery() })
    });
    const graphqlSchemaObj = buildClientSchema((await response.json()).data);
    const sdlString = printSchema(graphqlSchemaObj);
    fs.writeFileSync(filename, sdlString);
}

saveSchema("https://example.com/graphql", "schema.graphql");
```

`getIntrospectionQuery()` has the complete introspection query you need to get everything, and then `buildClientSchema()` and `printSchema()` turns the JSON mess into GraphQL SDL.

Wouldn't be too difficult to make this into a CLI tool itself but that feels like overkill.

Comment: `gql-sdl` does the job really well with no upfront configuration, thanks! Usage example: `gql-sdl http://localhost:4000/graphql -o schema-autogenerated.graphql -H \"Authorization: Bearer <id token>"`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Hasura's `graphqurl` utility

```sh
npm install -g graphqurl

gq <endpoint> --introspect > schema.graphql

# or if you want it in json
gq <endpoint> --introspect --format json > schema.json
```

Full documentation: https://github.com/hasura/graphqurl

Comment: This library is now unmaintained with outdated and vulnerable dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GraphQL-Codegen with the ast-plugin](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/schema-ast)

```sh
npm install --save graphql
npm install --save-dev @graphql-codegen/cli
npx graphql-codegen init
```

Follow the steps to generate the `codegen.yml` file

Once the tool is installed, you can use the plugin to download the schema which is [schema-ast](https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/schema-ast)

The best is to follow the instruction on the page to install it… but basically:

`npm install --save-dev @graphql-codegen/schema-ast`

Then configure the `codegen.yml` file to set which schema(s) is/are the source of truth and where to put the downloaded schema(s) file:

```yaml
schema:
  - 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'
generates:
  path/to/file.graphql:
    plugins:
      - schema-ast
    config:
      includeDirectives: true
```

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking and came across this [Medium article on GraphQL](https://medium.com/@mrthankyou/how-to-get-a-graphql-schema-28915025de0e)

The below query returned many details regarding schema, queries and their input & output params type.

```
fragment FullType on __Type {
  kind
  name
  fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
    name
    args {
      ...InputValue
    }
    type {
      ...TypeRef
    }
    isDeprecated
    deprecationReason
  }
  inputFields {
    ...InputValue
  }
  interfaces {
    ...TypeRef
  }
  enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
    name
    isDeprecated
    deprecationReason
  }
  possibleTypes {
    ...TypeRef
  }
}
fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
  name
  type {
    ...TypeRef
  }
  defaultValue
}
fragment TypeRef on __Type {
  kind
  name
  ofType {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
      kind
      name
      ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
          kind
          name
          ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
              kind
              name
              ofType {
                kind
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
query IntrospectionQuery {
  __schema {
    queryType {
      name
    }
    mutationType {
      name
    }
    types {
      ...FullType
    }
    directives {
      name
      locations
      args {
        ...InputValue
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can download a remote GraphQL server's schema with the following command. When the command succeeds, you should see a new file named `schema.json` in the current working directory.

`~$ npx apollo-cli download-schema $GRAPHQL_URL --output schema.json`

Answer (score 3):

You can use IntelliJ plugin `JS GraphQL` then IDEA will ask you create two files "graphql.config.json" and "graphql.schema.json"

Then you can edit "graphql.config.json" to point to your local or remote GraphQL server:

```
"schema": {
"README_request" : "To request the schema from a url instead, remove the 'file' JSON property above (and optionally delete the default graphql.schema.json file).",
"request": {
  "url" : "http://localhost:4000",
  "method" : "POST",
  "README_postIntrospectionQuery" : "Whether to POST an introspectionQuery to the url. If the url always returns the schema JSON, set to false and consider using GET",
  "postIntrospectionQuery" : true,
  "README_options" : "See the 'Options' section at https://github.com/then/then-request",
  "options" : {
    "headers": {
      "user-agent" : "JS GraphQL"
    }
  }
}
```

After that IDEA plugin will auto load schema from GraphQL server and show the schema json in the console like this:

```
Loaded schema from 'http://localhost:4000': {"data":{"__schema":{"queryType":{"name":"Query"},"mutationType":{"name":"Mutation"},"subscriptionType":null,"types":[{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"Query","description":"","fields":[{"name":"launche
```

Comment: Version 2 of this plugin will be soon available (now it's beta: https://github.com/jimkyndemeyer/js-graphql-intellij-plugin/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta-1 ). Instead of `graphql.config.json` file, there is `.graphqlconfig` file. You have to set field `schemaPath` to non-existing file (it will be auto created after downloading schema) and `url` to GraphQL remote server. Next, in tab "Schemas and project structure" (in "GraphQL" tab), double click on selected "Endpoint" and click "Get GraphQL Schema from Endpoint (introspection)". In previously mentioned file will be downloaded schema.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010467/10189759

Would like to point out that if authentications are needed, that you probably cannot just use the config file generated from `graphql init`

You might have to do something like this,   for example, using the github graphql API

```
{
  "projects": {
    "graphqlProjectTestingGraphql": {
      "schemaPath": "schema.graphql",
      "extensions": {
        "endpoints": {
          "dev": {
            "url": "https://api.github.com/graphql",
            "headers": {
              "Authorization": "Bearer <Your token here>"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql)  npm package's `IntrospectionQuery` [does](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/29b811fca5f726c9a3aa1d979c70ecbced8b4ec8/src/utilities/getIntrospectionQuery.ts#L37-L164)

```
query IntrospectionQuery {
    __schema {
        queryType {
            name
        }
        mutationType {
            name
        }
        subscriptionType {
            name
        }
        types {
            ...FullType
        }
        directives {
            name
            description

            locations
            args {
                ...InputValue
            }
        }
    }
}

fragment FullType on __Type {
    kind
    name
    description

    fields(includeDeprecated: true) {
        name
        description
        args {
            ...InputValue
        }
        type {
            ...TypeRef
        }
        isDeprecated
        deprecationReason
    }
    inputFields {
        ...InputValue
    }
    interfaces {
        ...TypeRef
    }
    enumValues(includeDeprecated: true) {
        name
        description
        isDeprecated
        deprecationReason
    }
    possibleTypes {
        ...TypeRef
    }
}

fragment InputValue on __InputValue {
    name
    description
    type {
        ...TypeRef
    }
    defaultValue
}

fragment TypeRef on __Type {
    kind
    name
    ofType {
        kind
        name
        ofType {
            kind
            name
            ofType {
                kind
                name
                ofType {
                    kind
                    name
                    ofType {
                        kind
                        name
                        ofType {
                            kind
                            name
                            ofType {
                                kind
                                name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/29b811fca5f726c9a3aa1d979c70ecbced8b4ec8/src/utilities/getIntrospectionQuery.ts#L37-L164)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it by your self, read these code:

There is a modular state-of-art tool 「graphql-cli」, consider looking at it. It uses package 「graphql」's buildClientSchema to build IDL .graphql file from introspection data.

- [graphql-cli get-schema :integrated into graphql-cli part 1](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-cli/blob/master/src/cmds/get-schema.ts)
- [graphql-config EndpointsExtension :integrated into graphql-cli part 2](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-config/blob/8f696c5f01bbf6851877e4a7f60cc720997aece1/src/extensions/endpoints/EndpointsExtension.ts#L130)

Comment: https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema 
  https://github.com/gabrielf/graphql-schema-from-introspection .  Two separated packages FYI.

Answer (score 0):

### Update - Jan 2024

You can hit server with below simple query now. It should work with most servers - I verified with DGS and Speaker

```
query {
    _service {
        sdl
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `apollo codegen:client`. See https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output