# How to get the type names of the query in graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

Hi I want to get the type names of the query in graphql. It should not have scalar and enumerated types.

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type LearningResource{
    id: ID
    name: String
    type: String
    children: [LearningResource]
}

type Query {
    fetchLearningResource: LearningResource
}
```

When I run `fetchLearningResource` query then I want to get the type of it like here `LearningResource`. Any way to do this in GraphQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You should find the Type of the Query as a string in the Response, search for `__typename`.

E.g.

```js
response =>

{
   fetchLearningResource: {
      id: <id>
      name: "name"
      type: "type"
      children: [...]
      __typename: "LearningResource"
   }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to fetch the query definition before you query. You could get the introspection query from the server. Here are some links:

[introspection query error](https://github.com/apollographql/eslint-plugin-graphql/issues/18)

[retrieve whole schema question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010467/2418739)

Comment: I don't have an response, before getting response I need to get the type of that query. I need to do something

Comment: Please explain better what you would like to do and why you need the query response type

Comment: I want to extract the type of the query then want to perform some action, like finding mapping against that type in database

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible. I will update my answer with some links